# useSelector Hook - Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, next.js

Why i got this error?

> Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body
> of a function component.

Here's my code in **useSession.js**:

```
import { useSelector } from 'react-redux';

export const useSession = () => {  
  const session = useSelector(state => state.session)
  return session
}
```

And code in **Auth.js**

```
import { useSession } from './useSession';

export const getServerSideProps = options => gssp => {

    const { signedIn, redirectTo } = options;

    return async ctx => {
      const session = useSession();

      if (signedIn && !session) {
        return {
          redirect: {
            destination: redirectTo || '/login',
            permanent: false,
          }
        }
      }

      const result = await gssp(ctx);

      return {
        ...result,
        props: {
          ...result.props,
          session,
        },
      }
    }
  };
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are breaking the rules of hooks. Namely [Don’t call Hooks from regular JavaScript functions.](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-from-react-functions) You can only use a hook from synchronous render of a react functional component. But here you are calling a hook from a plain javascript function that could be executed at any time.

To fix this you'll have to move the hook to the root level of your component.

For example:

```
function MyComp() {
  const session = useSelector(state => state.session)
  return <></>
}
```

If you want to encapsulate that logic into something reusable, you can make a custom hook.

```
export const useSession = () => { // note the name starts with `use`.
  const session = useSelector(state => state.session)
  return session
}
```

Which then must obey the rules of hooks itself:

```
function MyComp() {
  const session = useSession()
  return <></>
}
```

Comment: i am solving the problem according to your instructions but something is wrong for my case. I have updated my question, can you help me?

Comment: `useSession` is a custom _hook_ now, which must also obey the [rules of hooks](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-rules.html#only-call-hooks-from-react-functions). You are not calling `useSession` from the root level of a functional react component, so it won't work. Reread my answer and read that linked page on the react documentation. They tell you how to architect your code the right way.