# Followed different suggestions but still get "Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body of a function component"

Tags: react-hooks

I'm getting

> Error: Invalid hook call. Hooks can only be called inside of the body
> of a function component.

I followed different suggestions here on other questions and also on other forums. The last I tried is [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69834466/useselector-hook-invalid-hook-call-hooks-can-only-be-called-inside-of-the-bod), but still I can't figure out what's the problem with my code:

```
function myFunc() {
  const locale = useSelector((state) => state.locale);
  return <></>;
}
```

I am really new to react so don't hesistate to tell me if you need me to post further details

Comment: Did you tried to write your function name in Pascal Case (MyFunc) ? Sorry for this answer, I can't comment because i'm new in Stack Overflow.

Comment: Yes, I tried...but still get the same error

Comment: Try with const myFunc = () => { instead of function myFunc() as this link shows https://react-redux.js.org/api/hooks

Comment: I already tried also that...